# How to automatically generate and update function declarations (prototypes) for .h file in CLion?

Tags: c, clion, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to let CLion update the declaration in the .h file if I change the function definition in the .c file ?

The copy and pasting is such a repetitive task..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on changes I guess. I always use `Refactor->Change Signature` to update function return type, name, arguments in both files (source and header).